# Sticky element with LocomotiveScroll doesn't work

Tags: css, next.js, sticky, smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll

for a personal project I'm using Nextjs and locomotive-scroll, I'm trying to stick an element with  `position:sticky;` and  `data-scroll-sticky` but it's still not work, here is the code:

```js
import LocomotiveScroll from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/locomotive-scroll@4.1.4";

const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
  smooth: true
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div data-scroll-container>
  <section id="section-1" data-scroll-section>
    <div class="sticky" data-scroll data-scroll-sticky data-scroll-target="#section-1">
      sticky content
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis suscipit ut orci nec malesuada. Integer condimentum auctor orci, non aliquam ex finibus blandit. Pellentesque suscipit mi egestas augue elementum consectetur. Sed suscipit, metus ut tempor
      hendrerit, nulla leo auctor sapien, a mollis neque lorem vitae sapien. Curabitur eleifend, metus eu luctus malesuada, tortor est facilisis est, ut tempor libero lorem et nisl. Donec vitae gravida augue, in finibus lectus. Integer gravida elementum
      mi ut ultricies. Mauris non blandit dui. Praesent quis ante et orci sollicitudin molestie feugiat ac magna. Sed vitae tincidunt urna, vitae placerat tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      Vivamus molestie felis nibh, in lobortis purus malesuada ac. Proin pellentesque sodales quam, at lacinia odio cursus et. Vestibulum blandit felis quis orci tincidunt, sit amet dignissim nibh porttitor. Nullam urna lorem, convallis lacinia ipsum
      sit amet, efficitur interdum elit. Donec sit amet lobortis nibh. Mauris molestie augue nunc. Nam eget lacinia nisl, ut ullamcorper nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam malesuada
      pellentesque risus quis dapibus. Vivamus a enim iaculis, sollicitudin nisi a, dapibus lectus. Nullam malesuada est tortor, ut aliquet mi faucibus et. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt commodo. Quisque nibh metus, egestas et commodo quis, sollicitudin
      eget justo. Proin vestibulum leo est, vitae euismod nibh ornare ac. Curabitur tempus orci metus, vel sodales dui malesuada ut. Integer lobortis eros justo, sit amet feugiat odio rutrum non. Pellentesque molestie porttitor est et tempus. Etiam quis
      lorem urna. Quisque quam ex, pulvinar at eleifend nec, iaculis quis nisi. In feugiat laoreet consectetur. Suspendisse molestie, nibh ullamcorper suscipit cursus, diam libero consequat ex, in sodales est augue ut ante. Curabitur dapibus iaculis magna
      nec cursus. Donec convallis iaculis massa nec vulputate. Etiam elementum, urna sit amet ullamcorper pretium, enim arcu tincidunt mauris, non laoreet augue felis eu felis. Praesent hendrerit ullamcorper maximus. In pretium dui vitae odio accumsan
      ultricies. In interdum quis tortor quis viverra. Duis mi sem, cursus ac est sed, commodo venenatis ante. Proin ac ipsum nisi. Donec vestibulum ultrices risus, vitae aliquet quam rutrum eu. Suspendisse a arcu nec nulla molestie porta nec non enim.
      Nulla facilisis, urna in convallis feugiat, ligula magna viverra ex, quis pharetra felis erat quis est. Proin dictum accumsan quam non fringilla. Etiam bibendum, ipsum non rhoncus malesuada, quam ligula cursus nisi, eget maximus erat odio nec enim.
      Nunc ut porttitor nibh. Pellentesque neque velit, feugiat quis dapibus eget, ultrices ut odio. Fusce iaculis fermentum ipsum sed porta. Nam elit orci, euismod sit amet sapien vitae, mollis gravida ligula. Nulla egestas, est id rutrum consectetur,
      arcu nibh gravida augue, sit amet efficitur magna enim in urna. Vestibulum eu lacus dictum, interdum ipsum ut, placerat enim. Quisque posuere mi turpis, quis placerat turpis mattis vitae. Nulla in felis at dui auctor aliquam blandit a mi. Cras vitae
      viverra dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section-2" data-scroll-section>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
      Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
      mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tammura/pen/yLqYevx)

thank u all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [locomotive-scroll.css](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll/blob/master/dist/locomotive-scroll.css) as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll#css).

It should make your code work without the empty gap that appears at the beginning of the page. It will also add the CSS styling required for the locomotive-scroll to work properly.

```js
import LocomotiveScroll from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/locomotive-scroll@4.1.4";

const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
  smooth: true
});
```

```css
@import url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll/master/dist/locomotive-scroll.css);

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}


/*! locomotive-scroll v4.1.3 | MIT License | https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll */

html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.has-scroll-dragging {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.has-scroll-smooth body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-scroll-smooth [data-scroll-container] {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-container] {
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-section] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.c-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.45);
}

.c-scrollbar:hover,
.has-scroll-scrolling .c-scrollbar,
.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar {
  opacity: 1;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.3);
}

.c-scrollbar_thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-scroll-container>
  <section id="section-1" data-scroll-section>
    <div class="sticky" data-scroll data-scroll-sticky data-scroll-target="#section-1">
      sticky content
    </div>
    <div>
      ulum ultrices risus, vitae aliquet quam rutrum eu. Suspendisse a arcu nec nulla molestie porta nec non enim. Nulla facilisis, urna in convallis feugiat, ligula magna viverra ex, quis pharetra felis erat quis est. Proin dictum accumsan quam non fringilla.
      Etiam bibendum, ipsum non rhoncus malesuada, quam ligula cursus nisi, eget maximus erat odio nec enim. Nunc ut porttitor nibh. Pellentesque neque velit, feugiat quis dapibus eget, ultrices ut odio. Fusce iaculis fermentum ipsum sed porta. Nam elit
      orci, euismod sit amet sapien vitae, mollis gravida ligula. Nulla egestas, est id rutrum consectetur, arcu nibh gravida augue, sit amet efficitur magna enim in urna. Vestibulum eu lacus dictum, interdum ipsum ut, placerat enim. Quisque posuere mi
      turpis, quis placerat turpis mattis vitae. Nulla in felis at dui auctor aliquam blandit a mi. Cras vitae viverra dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section-2" data-scroll-section>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncte eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
      eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget
      dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncte eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut
      metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncte eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor
      eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies
      nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt
      tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue
      velit cursus nunc,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
      eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
      Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
      varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem
      neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
      leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you check on codeine it doesn't work because using locomotive-scroll I don't know why it doesn't work. but without locomotive-scroll your solution works fine.

Comment: @AhmedAmer, I tried figuring out the issue, and apparently, to make locomotive-scroll work, you must include their custom CSS. I checked it on my local server, and it worked fine. Please check my edited answer above :)

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it's work also without top:0, I forgot to import their custom css on my project

Comment: @AhmedAmer, I removed the unnecessary part from my answer and updated it :)